# Date.getDay() javascript returns wrong day

Tags: javascript, date

I have such javascript code

```
alert(DATE.value);
var d = new Date(DATE.value);
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDay();
alert(month);
alert(day);
if(2012 < year < 1971 | 1 > month+1 > 12 | 0 >day > 31){
    alert(errorDate);
    DATE.focus();
    return false;
}
```

take for instance: `DATE.value = "11/11/1991"`

when I call `alert(day);` it shows me `3`;
when I call `alert(d);` it is returns me correct info.

Comment: [Was monday...](http://www.dayoftheweek.org/?m=November&d=11&y=1991&go=Go)

Answer (score 448, accepted):

use `.getDate` instead of `.getDay`.

> The value returned by getDay is an integer corresponding to the day of the week: 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, and so on.

Comment: Really dumb that the designer of this function didn't call it getDayOf Week. No, that would have been too obvious.

Comment: @AndroidDev I do agree! Moreover with `.getDate` one would expect to be returned the full date, not just the day.

Comment: Here's more: function getMonth returns an integer from 0 to 11, with 0 for January and 11 for December. They must be smoking some heavy stuff over there

Comment: Here is EVEN more: getYear() actually the year minus 1900 !

Comment: Totally incongruent design ~ `Date.getYear() okay, Date.getMonth() okay, Date.getDate() what? `

Answer (score 22):

`getDay()` returns the day of the week. You can however use the `getDate()` method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Answer (score 19):

`getDay()` will give you the day of the week. You are looking for `getDate()`.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem. `date.getMonth()` returns an index ranging from `0 to 11`. January is `0`. If you create a new `date()`-object and you want to get information about a costum date not the current one you have to decrease only the month by `1`.

**Like this**:

```
function getDayName () {
var year = 2016;
var month = 4;
var day = 11;

var date = new Date(year, month-1, day);
var weekday = new Array("sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday",
                    "thursday", "friday", "saturday");

return weekday[date.getDay()];
}
```

Comment: Awesome Sven... that is the solution for my, minus one at moth... thanks.

Answer (score 4):

From now on you probably want to use the following below functions for Date objects:

```js
    function dayOf(date)
    {
        return date.getDate();
    }

    function monthOf(date)
    {
        return date.getMonth() + 1;
    }

    function yearOf(date)
    {
        return date.getYear() + 1900;
    }

    function weekDayOf(date)
    {
        return date.getDay() + 1;
    }
    
    var date = new Date("5/15/2020");
    console.log("Day: " + dayOf(date));
    console.log("Month: " + monthOf(date));
    console.log("Year: " + yearOf(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function formatDate(date, callback)
{
var weekday = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",     "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
var day = weekday[date.getDay()];
console.log('day',day);
var d = date.getDate();
var hours = date.getHours();
ampmSwitch = (hours > 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
if (hours > 12) {
    hours -= 12;

}
else if (hours === 0) {
    hours = 12;
}
var m = date.getMinutes();
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var month = months[date.getMonth()];
var year = date.getFullYear();
newdate = day + ', ' + month + ' ' + d + ',' + year + ' at ' + hours + ":" + m + " " + ampmSwitch
callback(newdate)
}
```

and call with this code

```
date="Fri Aug 26 2016 18:06:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
formatDate(date,function(result){
   console.log('Date=',result);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the function .getDay(), this one consider the month's number start in 0 and not in 1, then if you use the date new Date(2021-11-04), the .getDay() function will consider the day 4 of dezember and not november...

Then, to get de day 4 of november, you need pass "2021-10-04" to the Date() class.

Comment: As Ash mentioned below, "getDay() will give you the day of the week. You are looking for getDate()."

Answer (score 0):

It may also be an issue with the technology used and the browser ES5 compatible.

I had such a problem while developing an application in react native.

```
return `${date.getDay()} ${month}, ${date.getFullYear()}`;
```

to

```
return `${date.getDate()} ${month}, ${date.getFullYear()}`;
```